# Plotting a 2d numpy array with custom colors

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 2d numpy array that I want to plot so I can see how each category is positioned on the grid. The matrix (mat) looks something like this:

```
156 138 156
1300 137 156
138 138 1300
137 137 137
```

I plotted this as follows:

```
 plt.imshow(mat, cmap='tab20', interpolation='none')
```

However, I want to have custom colors. I have a csv where the id's correspond with the values in the matrix:

```
id,R,G,B
156,200,200,200
138,170,255,245
137,208,130,40
1300,63,165,76
```

Is there a way I can have the values in the matrix correspond with the R, G, B values in the csv file?

Edit: someone asked for a clarification but the entire answer was deleted.

each row has an ID and a 3 columns, representing the respective R, G, and B values. So the first row has ID 156 (a domain specific code) with R 200, G 200 and B 200 (which is grey).

Now I have a 2d matrix that I want to plot, and on each coordinate where the value is 156 I want that pixel to be grey. Same with ID 1300, where the colors 63, 165, and 76 represent a green color that I want to use in the matrix.

Comment: In my opinion `imshow` leads to a false understanding of your data, because I associate it with some level of continuity.  I'd prefer `scatter`, using very large dots, to transmit to the viewer a sense of the discreteness(?) of your data. If you agree I could post another answer using `scatter`.  Please let me know if you are interested.

Comment: But does that change how the image looks like? I am not sure if I completely understand your point but I am interested nonetheless.

Comment: Yes, of course the look of the image changes. That's exactly my point: the current plot (by `imshow`) _suggests_ that you are representing a continuous, generally differentiable field --- on the other hand your data, as far as I can tell, is discrete and discrete data is frequently shown using `scatter`, with color representing a _z_ value.

Comment: Ok yeah sorry it was a little bit of a stupid comment, I meant I am not sure how it changes. But I'd love to see your example. The pictures were slightly different from what I expected, so maybe the scatter fixes the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Using a colormap

In principle the matrix with RGB values is some kind of colormap. It makes sense to use a colormap in matplotlib to get the colors for a plot. What makes this a little more complicated here is that the values are not well spaced. So one idea would be to map them to integers starting at 0 first. Then creating a colormap from those values and using it with a BoundaryNorm allows to have a equidistant colorbar. Finally one may set the ticklabels of the colorbar back to the initial values.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

a =np.array([[156, 138, 156],
             [1300, 137, 156],
             [138, 138, 1300],
             [137, 137, 137]])

ca = np.array([[156,200,200,200],
               [138,170,255,245],
               [137,208,130,40],
               [1300,63,165,76]])

u, ind = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)
b = ind.reshape((a.shape))

colors = ca[ca[:,0].argsort()][:,1:]/255.
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors)
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(np.arange(len(ca)+1)-0.5, len(ca))

plt.imshow(b, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

cb = plt.colorbar(ticks=np.arange(len(ca)))
cb.ax.set_yticklabels(np.unique(ca[:,0]))

plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Plotting RGB array

You may create an RGB array from your data to directly plot as `imshow`. To this end you may index the original array with the colors from the color array and reshape the resulting array such that it is in the correct shape to be plotted with imshow.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


a =np.array([[156, 138, 156],
             [1300, 137, 156],
             [138, 138, 1300],
             [137, 137, 137]])

ca = np.array([[156,200,200,200],
               [138,170,255,245],
               [137,208,130,40],
               [1300,63,165,76]])

u, ind = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)
c = ca[ca[:,0].argsort()][:,1:]/255.

b =  np.moveaxis(c[ind][:,:,np.newaxis],1,2).reshape((a.shape[0],a.shape[1],3))
plt.imshow(b)
plt.show()
```

The result is the same as above, but without colorbar (as there is no quantity to map here).

Comment: Your second part raises an error: 

    AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'moveaxis'

But your first part works perfectly. I just removed **cb** variable to remove the colorbar.

Comment: `moveaxis` is available in numpy version 1.12 or higher, possibly you have an older version installed.

Answer (score 6):

It's not particularly elegant, but it is simple

```
In [72]: import numpy as np
In [73]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [74]: a = np.mat("156 138 156;1300 137 156;138 138 1300;137 137 137")
In [75]: d = {   156:  [200,  200,  200],
    ...:         138:  [170,  255,  245],
    ...:         137:  [208,  130,   40],
    ...:        1300:   [63,  165,   76]}
In [76]: image = np.array([[d[val] for val in row] for row in a], dtype='B')
In [77]: plt.imshow(image);
```

[image: the plot is here]

The point is to generate an array of the correct `dtype` ('B' encodes short unsigned integer) containing the correct (and unpacked) RGB  tuples.

---

#### Addendum

Following an exchange of comments following [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47776318/2749397) in this Addendum I'll propose a possible solution to the problem of plotting the same type of data using `plt.scatter()` (the problem was a bit tougher than I expected...)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import choices, randrange

######## THIS IS FOR IMSHOW ######################################
# the like of my previous answer
values = [20,150,900,1200]
rgb = lambda x=255:(randrange(x), randrange(x), randrange(x))
colord = {v:rgb() for v in values}

nr, nc = 3, 5
data = np.array(choices(values, k=nr*nc)).reshape((nr,nc))
c = np.array([[colord[v] for v in row] for row in data], dtype='B')

######## THIS IS FOR SCATTER ######################################
# This is for having the coordinates of the scattered points, note that rows' indices
# map to y coordinates and columns' map to x coordinates
y, x = np.array([(i,j) for i in range(nr) for j in range(nc)]).T
# Scatter does not expect a 3D array of uints but a 2D array of RGB floats
c1 = (c/255.0).reshape(nr*nc,3)

######## THIS IS FOR PLOTTING ######################################
# two subplots, plot immediately the imshow
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
ax1.imshow(c)
# to make a side by side comparison we set the boundaries and aspect
# of the second plot to mimic imshow's
ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())
ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
ax2.set_aspect(1)
# and finally plot the data --- the size of dots `s=900` was by trial and error
ax2.scatter(x, y, c=c1, s=900)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to add that (as noted in many SO posts, just search for 'numpy fromfunction' and the first hits will suffice to convince you) that the docstring for `np.fromfunction` is REALLY misleading...

Answer (score 3):

Pandas can help you to collect data:

```
im = pd.read_clipboard(header=None)  # from your post
colours = pd.read_clipboard(index_col=0,sep=',')  # from your post
```

Pandas helps also for the colormap :

```
colordf = colours.reindex(arange(1301)).fillna(0).astype(np.uint8)
```

And `numpy.take` build the image :

```
rgbim = colordf.values.take(im,axis=0))
```

`plt.imshow(rgbim):`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas and numpy, (Edit for n x m matrix):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 2
m = 2
df = pd.read_csv('matrix.txt')
id = df.id.values
id = np.reshape(id, (n, m))
R = df.R.values
R = np.reshape(R/255, (n, m))
G = df.R.values
G = np.reshape(G/255, (n, m))
B = df.B.values
B = np.reshape(B/255, (n, m))
img = []

for i in range(n):
    img.append([])
    for j in range(m):
        img[i].append((R[i][j], G[i][j], B[i][j]))

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```