# Using color with np.array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following x,y scatter points with numpy

```
a = np.array([
[5.033,-3.066],
[5.454,-3.492],
[-1.971,0.384],
],)
x, y = a.T
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.ylabel('Yv')
plt.show()
```

And I would like to draw points with color. I mean, something like this:

```
a = np.array([
[5.033,-3.066] and color="black",
[5.454,-3.492] and color="black",
[-1.971,0.384] and color="red",
],)
```

How can I do that? I see a colormap discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776318/plotting-a-2d-numpy-array-with-custom-colors), but don't know if that really fits my need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Adding colors

Simply create a list of colors corresponding to each of your inner lists, then give it to the parameter `color` of the scatter method :

```
colors = ["black", "black", "red"]
plt.scatter(x, y, color=colors)
```

Result :

[image: scatter plot with colored markers]

You can use strings to specify the colors you want. The available color strings are all HTML color names (in any upper or lower case). Check them all here: [HTML colors](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp)

You can also give hexadecimal RGB values like this (example for pink):

> '#FFB6C1'

... or as a tuple or list of RGB values ranged from 0 to 1, like this (still for pink):

> [1.0, 0.75, 0.8]

Source: [Matplotlib Colors Documentation](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Matplotlib/api/colors_api.html#module-matplotlib.colors)

## Adding legends:

The simplest way is to scatter iteratively  by row:

```
a = np.array([
[5.033,-3.066],
[5.454,-3.492],
[-1.971,0.384],
],)
x, y = a.T

# Creating colors and class names beforehand.
colors = ["black", "black", "red"]
classes = ["class1", "class2","class3"]
# Calling scatter per row, to differentiate each class
for x_per_class, y_per_class, color, label in zip(x, y, colors, classes):
    plt.scatter(x=x_per_class, y=y_per_class, color=color, label=label)

# Adding legends
plt.legend()

plt.ylabel('Yv')
plt.show()
```

Result with legend:

[image: color scatter plot with legend]

Comment: Thank you. It is possible to show the legend or assign labels to colors. For example, red point is P1 and so on.

Comment: Yes you can, but I would do it a bit differently to keep it simple. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
colors = ['black', 'black', 'red']
a = np.array([
[5.033,-3.066],
[5.454,-3.492],
[-1.971,0.384],
],)
x, y = a.T
print(x, y)
plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors)

plt.ylabel('Yv')
plt.show()
```